# How to direct a user to a new route after login?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, angular-routing, mean.io

A user logs in on the `/` route.

1. How do I direct them away from the `/` view of my app

   ```
   /packages/system/public/views/index.html
   ```

   to another view `/app`?

   ```
   /packages/system/public/views/app.html
   ```
2. I want this view `/app` to be secure, so only logged in users can access it. Non-logged in users should be sent back to `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /packages/users/controllers/meanUser.js

```
  // Register the login() function
  $scope.login = function() {
    $http.post('/login', {
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password
    })
      .success(function(response) {
        // authentication OK
        $scope.loginError = 0;
        $rootScope.user = response.user;
        $rootScope.$emit('loggedin');
        if (response.redirect) {
          if (window.location.href === response.redirect) {
            //This is so an admin user will get full admin page
            window.location.reload();
          } else {
            window.location = response.redirect;
          }
        } else {
          // Redirect Here
          $location.url('/');
          $location.url('/articles'); // Will take you to the articles view after login
        }
      })
      .error(function() {
        $scope.loginerror = 'Authentication failed.';
      });
  };
```

If you need a user to be redirected to another page when they attempt to access a secured route without being logged in you can refer to the code in /packages/articles/public/routes/articles.js

```
// This function checks if the user is logged in and redirects to the login page.
var checkLoggedin = function($q, $timeout, $http, $location) {
  // Initialize a new promise
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  // Make an AJAX call to check if the user is logged in
  $http.get('/loggedin').success(function(user) {
    // Authenticated
    if (user !== '0') $timeout(deferred.resolve);

    // Not Authenticated
    else {
      $timeout(deferred.reject);
      $location.url('/login');
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};

// These are your defined routes.
$stateProvider
  .state('all articles', {
    url: '/articles',
    templateUrl: 'articles/views/list.html',
    // This resolve runs the checkLoggedin function as the route is accessed 
    // and redirects if the user isn't logged in.
    resolve: {
      loggedin: checkLoggedin
    }
  });
```

Comment: ok, great.  If the user isn't logged in and they visit /app, how do I send them to /auth/login?

Comment: @MichaelCole  I've edited my original answer to include the redirect if not auth'd code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Anyone has a better solution?